# Cannot find imported package in Golang

Tags: go

I am trying to learn Golang, and I have a beginners issue.

I created two files "helloworld.go" and "greetings.go". I am trying to import greetings.go into helloworld.go using

```
import (
    "test/greetings/greetings"
)
```

But I get the following error:

> cannot find package "test/greetings/greetings" in any of:
>         C:\Go\src\test\greetings\greetings (from $GOROOT)
>         C:\work\go-ws\src\test\greetings\greetings (from $GOPATH)       exit
>   status 1

I am using a windows OS and my GOPATH and GOROOT values are as follows:

```
"GOPATH": "C:/work/go-ws"
"GOROOT": "C:/Go"
```

My project structure is as shown:

```
C:
--work
   -- go-ws
      -- anlytics
          -- src
              -- test
                  -- greetings
                       **greetings.go**
                  **helloworld.go**
          -- pkg
          -- bin
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your GOPATH should be `C:/work/go-ws/anlytics`.

Comment: Thanks Tim, but I still get an error   cannot find package "test/greetings/greetings" in any of:
  C:\Go\src\test\greetings\greetings (from $GOROOT)
  C:\work\go-ws\anlytics\src\test\greetings\greetings (from $GOPATH)
 
 exit status 1

Comment: You do not import files, you import packages (think of them as whole directories). Read How to Write Go Code.

Comment: Just import "test/greetings"

Comment: I have a different error now:                                                         .\helloworld.go:4:2: imported and not used: "test/greetings"
 .\helloworld.go:9:10: undefined: Salutation

Comment: Never mind. I figured it. To use the 'Salutation' struct from the greetings.go, I had to append the greet package to the variable. Instead of 'Salutation', you use it with greet.Salutation. Thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 1):

To use the 'Salutation' struct from the greetings.go, I had to append the greet package to the variable. Instead of 'Salutation', you use it with greet.Salutation.

My greetigs.go file

```
package greet

import "fmt"

type Salutation struct {
    Name     string
    Greeting string
}
...
```

So to use it in my helloworld.go, I append greet to the variable as follows

```
package main

import (
    "test/greetings"
)

func main() {

    var s = greet.Salutation{"Bob", "Hello"}
}
```

And it works...